# Webapplication detecting Windhoek taxi numbers

Tags: image-processing, web-applications, image-recognition, text-recognition

I would like to build a web application, that can detect the registration numbers of Taxis in Windhoek. Those numbers always consist of a letter and a 3 digit number, here is an example:
[Windhoek taxi with number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y64Sh.png)

This number is displayed on both sites of the car and on the raer window.
I would like to have a phone's live camera footage being displayed on the webpage. An object detection and recognition algorithm should process the footage and return the taxi number(s) detected.

I am now searching for some advice on how to approach this problem.
Which libraries would you suggest? Where should I start first?
I hope you can give me some inspiration and tips :)
Thanks a lot in advance!